# Flutter- How to use image in container?

Tags: flutter

I am building an app and I am using a Container to design a card but here is a thing image should be 1/3 of the container and not fill up the entire container.
Here is the code for the container:

```
Container(
height: 240,
width: 160,
decoration: BoxDecoration(
image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('images/rest.jpg'),fit: BoxFit.cover),
borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
color: Color(0xFFFDEEDD),
),
child: Column(
children: <Widget>[
Text('Hello'),
Row(
children: <Widget>[
Text('World'),
Text('4.2'),
],
)
],
),
),
```

[Card I am trying to replicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1U2Fe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be better to use a `ClipRRect` here instead. If you use material, you can also use `ListTile` :

```
    return Material(
        child: Center(
            child: Container(
                color: Colors.black12,
                width: 250,
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children:[
                        ClipRRect(
                            child:Image.network("https://via.placeholder.com/250"),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                            title: Text("The fifties"),
                            subtitle: Text("Subtitle"),
                        )
                    ]
                )
            )
        )
    );
```